# Will angels be with us in Paradise?

Tags: quran, hadith, jannah, malaikah

After resurrection of all creatures, will the main angels that were mentioned mainly in the quran disappear forever? Like Jibril, Mikael, Israfil, and angel of death? What if we wish to see these angels in paradise InshAllah? It seems unfair if they do disappear considering how much they've done for humanity. It would be sad to see them go. I was hoping they would be with us in the afterlife as well. Jazakallah for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

In the Name of Allah—the Most Compassionate, Most Merciful،
I believe that all people with real faith will see and talk to angels ,
angels will welcome them at heavens entrance  :
"
the Gardens of Eternity, which they will enter along with the righteous among their parents, spouses, and descendants. And the angels will enter upon them from every gate, ˹saying,˺ “Peace be upon you for your perseverance. How excellent is the ultimate abode!”
((AR-Ra'd verse 23))

The Supreme Horror ˹of that Day˺ will not disturb them, and the angels will greet them, ˹saying,˺ “This is your Day, which you have been promised.”
((AL-Anbya verse 103))

And many other verses in quran Angels are talking to people in heaven.

Comment: What about the above angels I’ve mentioned?

Comment: So what makes you think they will disappear !! Do you know hadieth or verse that mention that !!

Comment: There was a hadith that stated Malak al maut will take the souls of the following angels and himself. Am I correct or wrong?

Comment: Yes that's right but  before that he will take the souls of  all man kind  , and all other souls like animals, all that before the  Day of Resurrection, then Allah will raise all souls again , for Resurrection day.

Comment: Oh so Allah will resurrect all of them and put them where? In paradise?

Answer (score 1):

The angels will not disappear on Qiyamah.

There is disagreement over whether the angels will die or not. However, even those scholars who say they will die like everything else believe that they will be resurrected with everyone else.

Some evidence for this is that Allah mentions the angels of Paradise meeting and greeting the believers:

> Gardens of perpetual residence; they will enter them with whoever were righteous among their fathers, their spouses and their descendants. And the angels will enter upon them from every gate, [saying],
>
> "Peace be upon you for what you patiently endured. And excellent is the final home." (13:23-24)

Allah also mentions the angels of Hell who guard it and punish the people inside it:

> Over it (Hell) are nineteen [angels]. (74:30)
>
> And they (the people of Hell) will call, "O Malik (name of the angel guarding Hell), let your Lord put an end to us!" He will say, "Indeed, you will remain." (43:77)

There is no reason to suggest any angels will "disappear forever."

Comment: Salam! It’s only a question because I’ve heard speculations that after the angel of death claims the soul of everyone, he will take the souls of Jibril, Mikael, Israfil and himself. And so I figured if he did, would they be with us as resurrected souls in the hereafter or just gone?

Comment: @SabrinsSims See my second paragraph where I talked about the opinion that the angels will die on Qiyamah along with everyone else

Comment: Yes I realize they will all die but it’s mainly if they will come back or be gone permanently. That’s all brother/sister.

Comment: @SabrinsSims As I said there, no one believes the angels will die and be gone permanently. If they will die, they will also be resurrected

Comment: Okay thank you for the clarification! May Allah reunite us in jannat al firdous with the angels and our prophets and our families and friends who were righteous ameen. I appreciate it. I’m sorry if I sounded kind of dumb haha